# Rails, Devise can not use cURL to signout.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am following [this tutorial](http://lucatironi.github.io/tutorial/2012/10/15/ruby_rails_android_app_authentication_devise_tutorial_part_one/) to create user authentication with devise from Android. However, Devise remove `:token_authenticable` hence, I am using what they refer in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/josevalim/fb706b1e933ef01e4fb6). However, I ran into some issue which I have no idea how to resolve.

Here is the code.

in User model.

```
before_save :ensure_authentication_token

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
    :confirmable

def ensure_authentication_token
    if authentication_token.blank?
        self.authentication_token = generate_authentication_token
    end
end

def skip_confirmation!
    self.confirmed_at = Time.now
end

private
    def generate_authentication_token
        loop do
            token = Devise.friendly_token
            break token unless User.where(authentication_token: token).first
        end
    end
```

In application controller:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
before_filter :authenticate_user_from_token!

private
    # For this example, we are simply using token authentication
    # via parameters. However, anyone could use Rails's token
    # authentication features to get the token from a header.
    def authenticate_user_from_token!
        user_token = params[:user_token].presence
        user = user_token && User.find_by_authentication_token(user_token.to_s)

        if user
            # Notice we are passing store false, so the user is not
            # actually stored in the session and a token is needed
            # for every request. If you want the token to work as a
            # sign in token, you can simply remove store: false.
            sign_in user, store: false
        end 
    end
```

In SessionController API

```
class Api::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
 skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token,
                 :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
 before_action :authenticate_user_from_token!, only: [:create]
 respond_to :json
 def create
     warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
     render :status => 200,
     :json => { :success => true,
     :info => t("devise.sessions.signed_in"),
     :data => { :auth_token => current_user.authentication_token } }
 end

 def destroy
    warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
    current_user.update_column(:authentication_token, nil)
    render :status => 200,
    :json => { :success => true,
    :info => t("devise.sessions.signed_out"),
    :data => {} }
 end
```

end

When I perform curl to log in:

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: appl-H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/sessions -d "{\"user\":{\"email\":\"[FILTERED]\",\"password\":\"123123123\"}}"
```

Here is the log from server:

```
Started POST "/api/sessions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-23 13:47:05 +1300
Processing by Api::SessionsController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "session"=>{"user"=>{"email"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}}
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = '[FILTERED]'  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "current_sign_in_at" = ?, "last_sign_in_at" = ?, "sign_in_count" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = 1  [["current_sign_in_at", "2015-01-23 00:47:05.981119"], ["last_sign_in_at", "2015-01-23 00:28:49.300907"], ["sign_in_count", 3], ["updated_at", "2015-01-23 00:47:05.981736"]]
(103.8ms)  commit transaction
Completed 200 OK in 185ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 104.9ms)
```

And when I perform curl to logout :

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X DELETE http://localhost:3000/api/sessions/?auth_token=TbQXZJtngfJqZK6HkHKF
```

Here is the server log:

```
Started DELETE "/api/sessions/?auth_token=TbQXZJtngfJqZK6HkHKF" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-23 13:50:22 +1300
Processing by Api::SessionsController#destroy as JSON
Parameters: {"auth_token"=>"TbQXZJtngfJqZK6HkHKF", "session"=>{}}
Filter chain halted as :verify_signed_out_user rendered or redirected
Completed 204 No Content in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

When I add `skip_filter:verify_signed_out_user, only:[:destroy]` in SessionController API the server log would be:

```
Started DELETE "/api/sessions/?auth_token=TbQXZJtngfJqZK6HkHKF" for  127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-23 13:58:55 +1300
Processing by Api::SessionsController#destroy as JSON
Parameters: {"auth_token"=>"TbQXZJtngfJqZK6HkHKF", "session"=>{}}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
```

I don't get why it returns 204 with no content....
If anyone has some idea on what is going on. It would be very appreciated.
Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTTP status for having successfully destroyed a resource is 204. Check http://httpstatus.es/204 for more information.

When you skip the filter, it gives you 401, the HTTP status for Unauthorize entry to a resource. This is correct, because you ask for authentication before you can destroy the result.

Everything seems to be correct, I can see no problem.

Comment: Hi, the server log has this line `Filter chain halted as :verify_signed_out_user rendered or redirected`. Could you please explain that more?

Also, I render the status to 200 and render json information back to user. Why doesnt it show status 200 with info: "devise.sessions.signed_out"

Comment: Think of a Session as an object that gets destroyed when you close session. The line you provided shows a filter being activated.
If you look at the Devise's session controller [source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb), you'll see that the `destroy` action effectively returns `:no_content` and redirects to whatever post `after_sign_out` logic you implemented.